# HTML Nav tag not working as intended

Tags: html, nav

I am dabbling with html, and want to make  my own website. I was trying to get the links to my most frequently used websites on the left of the page, as i belive that is what nav does. Also, I can not seem to get the body of my text in the center of my page, nor the header. This is my code;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My first webpage</title>
  </head>
    <header>Ian Witkowski</header>
    <nav>
    <h1>My Favorite Websites</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href=http://www.youtube.com/>YouTube</a>
      <li><a href=http://www.google.com/>Google</a>
      <li><a href=http://www.reddit.com/>Reddit</a>
    </ul>
    </nav>
  <body>
    <article>
    <h1>The Penultimate Website</h1>
    <h2>The Official Homepage of Ian Witkowski</h2>
    <p>Thank you for visiting my webpage!</p>
    <dl>
      <dt><h3>Ian Witkowski</h3></dt>
      <dd>A cool dude</dd>
    </dl>
    <p>

    Reasons Ian is cool;</p>
    <ul>
      <li>He is nice</li>
      <li>He rides bikes</li>
      <li>He likes computers</li>
      <li>He can code his own website</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Here is a link for my arbitrary code test page;</p>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="secondpage.htm" target="_blank">Ian2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </article>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nav` does nothing. It's just a tag like `div`. But part of the HTML5 specification, they added `section, nav, footer, header` tag to simplify the description of the page.

Without css, it's just a tag without any special behavior regarding design

Second thing, you have error on your html. Everything thing except the head part shoud be inside body (including nav)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My first webpage</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>Ian Witkowski</header>
    <nav>
    <h1>My Favorite Websites</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href=http://www.youtube.com/>YouTube</a>
      <li><a href=http://www.google.com/>Google</a>
      <li><a href=http://www.reddit.com/>Reddit</a>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    <article>
    <h1>The Penultimate Website</h1>
    <h2>The Official Homepage of Ian Witkowski</h2>
    <p>Thank you for visiting my webpage!</p>
    <dl>
      <dt><h3>Ian Witkowski</h3></dt>
      <dd>A cool dude</dd>
    </dl>
    <p>

    Reasons Ian is cool;</p>
    <ul>
      <li>He is nice</li>
      <li>He rides bikes</li>
      <li>He likes computers</li>
      <li>He can code his own website</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Here is a link for my arbitrary code test page;</p>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="secondpage.htm" target="_blank">Ian2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </article>    
  </body>
</html>
```